# generate_series() function code

Tags: sql, postgresql, pentaho

Am trying to find the number of hours between 2 dates.

Excluding *sat* and *sun* and withing working hours(*9 am to 6 pm*).

I see that such codes exists `using generate_series()` function but unfortunately our version does not support this. am getting the below error:

```
ERROR: function generate_series(unknown, unknown, interval) does not exist
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.
Character: 43
```

It would help if I get the actual function code so that I can explicitly create that function and then use in my code,
else please let me know the alternate solution for this.

```
SELECT count(*) - 1 AS work_hours
FROM   generate_series ('receiveddateandtime'
                       ,'queryanswereddateandtime'
                       , interval '1h') h
WHERE  EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM h) < 6
AND    h::time >= '09:00'::time
AND    h::time <  '18:00'::time;
```

and the table structure is as below:

```
CREATE TABLE sc141901.fpa_daily_dump_22jan
(
  queryid integer NOT NULL,
  querydescription text,
  creatorid integer,
  creatorname text,
  receiveddateandtime text,
  buhorizontal text,
  buhorizontaldesc text,
  fpateamdl text,
  projectid integer,
  projectname text,
  customerid integer,
  customername text,
  parentcustomer text,
  typeofissue text,
  subcategory text,
  monthofcpr text,
  yearofcpr integer,
  amount_usd numeric(23,0),
  status text,
  pendingwith text,
  accountingissue integer,
  accountingissuecomments text,
  fpaanalystid integer,
  fpaanalystname text,
  respondeddateandtime text,
  daysforresolution integer,
  workingonitdateandtime text,
  coordinationwithotherteamdateandtime text,
  queryanswereddateandtime text,
  closeddateandtime text,
  comments text,
  insert_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
)
```

Comment: The full text of the query you're using will be helpful.  Probably the definition of the tables as well.

Comment: @E.S, when "improving formatting" please be careful to preserve whitespace.  The error message that you altered has a positional element that you relocated, which ends up changing the meaning of the error.  The use of quote formatting instead of a code block was an intentional choice.

Comment: You are passing string literals into the function `generate_series()`, not date values. If you want to generate dates, you need to pass date values.

Comment: @user3243383, thank you for adding the query... however, the query that you've provided does not match the error message.  Are you sure that you have properly copied the error and the query?

Comment: am sorry i recopied the error msg again...it says that function does not exist